# Applying texture to a single face

Tags: uv, displacement, 3d-printing

I am very new to Blender, and I am using the program mostly to learn how to apply a texture pattern to thing I will be 3D printing. So far I've learned pretty easily how to apply a Displace modifier to an object, the issue is I don't want to completely distort the entire mesh, but I can't seem to control that. I have tried unwrapping the UV, doing a Smart UV project, and using Project From View (Bounds) options and using the UVMap as the coordinates for the Displacement, but it seems to still be distorting the entire object. I have added a few pictures of what I've got set up, I'm sure I'm just missing something minor but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
[image: Heres what it looks like]
[image: This is Edit mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In edit mode, select the faces you want to displace and assign them to a vertex group.

Then use this group in the displace modifier.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.